# Get multiple integers from document, combine them, divide them by value and get the top result from collection

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to get the top "global" value(s) from mongodb collection.
Let's say I have this collection:

```
[{
  "_id": 1,
  "elo": {
    "kit1": 1020,
    "kit2": 1000,
    "kit3": 1007
  } 
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "elo": {
    "kit1": 1041,
    "kit2": 1065,
    "kit3": 1051
  }
}]
```

The global elo of `_id: 1` would be `1009` and `_id: 2` would be `1052`

So the result I am expecting is:

```
[
  {
  "_id": 2,
  "global": 1052
},
{
  "_id": 1,
  "global": 1009
}
]
```

I have written this query:

```
   ([
     { $group: ("global": { $sum: "/*What to do here when I have multiple values*/" } } },
     { $sort: { "global": -1 } },
     { $limit: 10 }}
   ])
```

but I am stuck on the $group part

Comment: Are the `kit1`, `kit2`, and `kit3` fields necessary? Would your collection still work if the `elo` field were an array?

Comment: aggregate with `project` instead of `group` check this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/

Comment: @JerodJohnson yes that is required, the actual kit names are different this is just an example

Comment: @Yogesh I will try that thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
   aggregate([
     { "$group": {"_id": "$_id", "global": {"$avg": "$elo"} } },
     { "$sort": { "global": -1 } },
     { "$limit": 10 }
   ]);
```

Comment: No that wouldn't work because it's not an array of ints

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution:

```
aggregate(asList(
  new Document("$project", 
    new Document("global", new BsonArray(getKitArray()))), 
  new Document("$skip", pos), 
  new Document("$limit", 1)));
```

Since I knew the kit ids, I basically wrapped them up in array which solved the problem

As for the getKitArray() I used this

```
List<BsonValue> kits = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < kits.size(); i++) {
    kits.add(new BsonString("$" + ArenaKit.kits.get(i).id));
}
return kits;
```